# how to take header cell globally in tableview

Tags: swift

```
override  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: section)

    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "header", for: myIndexPath) as? GuideheaderTableViewCell

     header?.dwnldBtn.isHidden = true

        header?.dwnldBtn.tag = section
        header?.dwnldBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(headerPressed(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)

    return header?.contentView
    }


 @objc func headerPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        print("Header tapped %@", sender.tag)
       let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: sender.tag)

         if hiddenSections.contains(sender.tag) 
{
            hiddenSections.remove(at: hiddenSections.index(of: sender.tag)!)

            tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sender.tag) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)

            tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
        }
        else 
{
            hiddenSections.append(sender.tag)
            tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sender.tag) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
        }

    }
```

I am hiding the `dwnldBtn` in the header, how can I show `dwnldBtn` on "headerPressed"?

Comment: headerPressed will never be executed. because you are hiding the dwnldBtn there. what exactly you wants to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for the response,Actually I am using download button in tableview cell.now i want download button on header but it will show only when "headerPressed" action is done @BhavinKansagara

Comment: headerPressed action will never be done. Because, you are hiding the dwnldBtn, in viewForHeader. How that action will be invoked?

Answer (score 0):

You can get section header from `tableView`

```
let header = tableView.headerViewForSection(section: sender.tag) as! GuideheaderTableViewCell
header?.dwnldBtn.isHidden = false
```